# How to edit cell in grid panel in Ext JS 3.4?

Tags: extjs, extjs3

Is it possible to make cell editable in ext js 3.4 `gridpanel`?

If yes please reply me how?

> This is the code I tried,

```
var fm = Ext.form;
var grid = new Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel({
    height: 500,
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 800,
    loadMask: false,
    viewConfig: {
        emptyText: 'No data to display'
    },
    selModel: checkboxselection,
    tbar: mainGridToolbar,
    clicksToEdit: 1,
    store: cartStore,
    listeners: {
        afteredit: function(o) {

            var pos = o.record.get('POS');
            var quantity = o.value;

        }
    },
    columns: [
        checkboxselection,
        {
            header: "quantity",
            align: 'right',
            dataIndex: 'QUANTITY',
            sortable: true,
            editor: new fm.TextField({
                allowBlank: false
            })
        }
    ]
});
```

Comment: You need to show what you've tried, that's the spirit of SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**

You are missing the plugin line... (I never heard of a EditorGridPanel, but I am on 4.x and may be mistaken at this point)

```
plugins: new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({saveText: 'Update'});
```

**Origin**

Use the Row Editor Plugin for these. You can specify for each cell if it should be editable or not.
You should really take look at the examples that comes along with the library! These lines can be found under ext-3.4.0\examples\grid\row-editor.js

```
Ext.onReady(function(){
Ext.QuickTips.init();

var Employee = Ext.data.Record.create([{
    name: 'name',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'email',
    type: 'string'
}, {
    name: 'start',
    type: 'date',
    dateFormat: 'n/j/Y'
},{
    name: 'salary',
    type: 'float'
},{
    name: 'active',
    type: 'bool'
}]);


// hideous function to generate employee data
var genData = function(){
    var data = [];
    var s = new Date(2007, 0, 1);
    var now = new Date(), i = -1;
    while(s.getTime() < now.getTime()){
        var ecount = Ext.ux.getRandomInt(0, 3);
        for(var i = 0; i < ecount; i++){
            var name = Ext.ux.generateName();
            data.push({
                start : s.clearTime(true).add(Date.DAY, Ext.ux.getRandomInt(0, 27)),
                name : name,
                email: name.toLowerCase().replace(' ', '.') + '@exttest.com',
                active: true,
                salary: Math.floor(Ext.ux.getRandomInt(35000, 85000)/1000)*1000
            });
        }
        s = s.add(Date.MONTH, 1);
    }
    return data;
}


var store = new Ext.data.GroupingStore({
    reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({fields: Employee}),
    data: genData(),
    sortInfo: {field: 'start', direction: 'ASC'}
});

var editor = new Ext.ux.grid.RowEditor({
    saveText: 'Update'
});

var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
    store: store,
    width: 600,
    region:'center',
    margins: '0 5 5 5',
    autoExpandColumn: 'name',
    plugins: [editor],
    view: new Ext.grid.GroupingView({
        markDirty: false
    }),
    tbar: [{
        iconCls: 'icon-user-add',
        text: 'Add Employee',
        handler: function(){
            var e = new Employee({
                name: 'New Guy',
                email: 'new@exttest.com',
                start: (new Date()).clearTime(),
                salary: 50000,
                active: true
            });
            editor.stopEditing();
            store.insert(0, e);
            grid.getView().refresh();
            grid.getSelectionModel().selectRow(0);
            editor.startEditing(0);
        }
    },{
        ref: '../removeBtn',
        iconCls: 'icon-user-delete',
        text: 'Remove Employee',
        disabled: true,
        handler: function(){
            editor.stopEditing();
            var s = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelections();
            for(var i = 0, r; r = s[i]; i++){
                store.remove(r);
            }
        }
    }],

    columns: [
    new Ext.grid.RowNumberer(),
    {
        id: 'name',
        header: 'First Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        width: 220,
        sortable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false
        }
    },{
        header: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        width: 150,
        sortable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            allowBlank: false,
            vtype: 'email'
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'datecolumn',
        header: 'Start Date',
        dataIndex: 'start',
        format: 'm/d/Y',
        width: 100,
        sortable: true,
        groupRenderer: Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('M y'),
        editor: {
            xtype: 'datefield',
            allowBlank: false,
            minValue: '01/01/2006',
            minText: 'Can\'t have a start date before the company existed!',
            maxValue: (new Date()).format('m/d/Y')
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'numbercolumn',
        header: 'Salary',
        dataIndex: 'salary',
        format: '$0,0.00',
        width: 100,
        sortable: true,
        editor: {
            xtype: 'numberfield',
            allowBlank: false,
            minValue: 1,
            maxValue: 150000
        }
    },{
        xtype: 'booleancolumn',
        header: 'Active',
        dataIndex: 'active',
        align: 'center',
        width: 50,
        trueText: 'Yes',
        falseText: 'No',
        editor: {
            xtype: 'checkbox'
        }
    }]
});

var cstore = new Ext.data.JsonStore({
    fields:['month', 'employees', 'salary'],
    data:[],
    refreshData: function(){
        var o = {}, data = [];
        var s = new Date(2007, 0, 1);
        var now = new Date(), i = -1;
        while(s.getTime() < now.getTime()){
            var m = {
                month: s.format('M y'),
                employees: 0,
                salary: 0,
                index: ++i
            }
            data.push(m);
            o[m.month] = m;
            s = s.add(Date.MONTH, 1);
        }
        store.each(function(r){
            var m = o[r.data.start.format('M y')];
            for(var i = m.index, mo; mo = data[i]; i++){
                mo.employees += 10000;
                mo.salary += r.data.salary;
            }
        });
        this.loadData(data);
    }
});
cstore.refreshData();
store.on('add', cstore.refreshData, cstore);
store.on('remove', cstore.refreshData, cstore);
store.on('update', cstore.refreshData, cstore);

var chart = new Ext.Panel({
    width:600,
    height:200,
    layout:'fit',
    margins: '5 5 0',
    region: 'north',
    split: true,
    minHeight: 100,
    maxHeight: 500,

    items: {
        xtype: 'columnchart',
        store: cstore,
        url:'../../resources/charts.swf',
        xField: 'month',
        yAxis: new Ext.chart.NumericAxis({
            displayName: 'Employees',
            labelRenderer : Ext.util.Format.numberRenderer('0,0')
        }),
        tipRenderer : function(chart, record, index, series){
            if(series.yField == 'salary'){
                return Ext.util.Format.number(record.data.salary, '$0,0') + ' total salary in ' + record.data.month;
            }else{
                return Ext.util.Format.number(Math.floor(record.data.employees/10000), '0,0') + ' total employees in ' + record.data.month;
            }
        },

        // style chart so it looks pretty
        chartStyle: {
            padding: 10,
            animationEnabled: true,
            font: {
                name: 'Tahoma',
                color: 0x444444,
                size: 11
            },
            dataTip: {
                padding: 5,
                border: {
                    color: 0x99bbe8,
                    size:1
                },
                background: {
                    color: 0xDAE7F6,
                    alpha: .9
                },
                font: {
                    name: 'Tahoma',
                    color: 0x15428B,
                    size: 10,
                    bold: true
                }
            },
            xAxis: {
                color: 0x69aBc8,
                majorTicks: {color: 0x69aBc8, length: 4},
                minorTicks: {color: 0x69aBc8, length: 2},
                majorGridLines: {size: 1, color: 0xeeeeee}
            },
            yAxis: {
                color: 0x69aBc8,
                majorTicks: {color: 0x69aBc8, length: 4},
                minorTicks: {color: 0x69aBc8, length: 2},
                majorGridLines: {size: 1, color: 0xdfe8f6}
            }
        },
        series: [{
            type: 'column',
            displayName: 'Salary',
            yField: 'salary',
            style: {
                image:'../chart/bar.gif',
                mode: 'stretch',
                color:0x99BBE8
            }
        }]
    }
});


var layout = new Ext.Panel({
    title: 'Employee Salary by Month',
    layout: 'border',
    layoutConfig: {
        columns: 1
    },
    width:600,
    height: 600,
    items: [chart, grid]
});
layout.render(Ext.getBody());

grid.getSelectionModel().on('selectionchange', function(sm){
    grid.removeBtn.setDisabled(sm.getCount() < 1);
});
});
```

Comment: Constructor Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel is actually available on ExtJS 3.4 and is working for inline- and row-edit (have it working here) - rather would say a colModel is missing. I'm new to ExtJS - but I guess the data-store won't be mapped without the column-model:

EditorGridPanel: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.EditorGridPanel

ColumnModel: http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.grid.ColumnModel

Comment: @syslogic columns get transformed into a ColumnModel. Plain spoken; that are the items of the columnmodel. So NO, this wasn't the error.